# How can I audit the special privileged (admin) users?

Tags: logging, admin, audit, graylog

I have Graylog web service for the audit logs. I need to control special privileged audits to check these all the time. I'm searching the admin logs on Graylog service for all our user and system accounts and using the tag "sudo".

How else can I find this special privileged admin logs on Graylog? I mean what should I write to the search tab besides "sudo".